# PHP: get contents of the aspx file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I got next problem. I need to get HTML of several pages. All works great with PHP functions file() or file_get_contents() or CURL.

But doesn't work for one URL!! [Here it is](http://albertacanada.com/immigration/immigrating/ainp-application-forms.aspx) (of course, I try to get HTML of non-shortened URL).

I tried all, nothing helps. I can open this page in browswer, it returns 200 status, but... I can't get it's contents! It returns **500 error**, when I try to get it via CURL:

```
Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP.ypDetectClass..ctor() +47
   ASP.immigration_immigrating_ainp_application_forms_aspx..ctor() +26
   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_obqstzij.Create_ASP_immigration_immigrating_ainp_application_forms_aspx() +20
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +32
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +119
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +160
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +93
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3623; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618 "
```

Comment: that's not possible to fix unless you can modify the aspx source code of the hosting site

Comment: Do you have permission to grab the HTML of this page? If so, ask the owner for help. They most likely block your request on purpose. If not, I don't think we can help you...

Comment: If you work with Linux, have you tried to get this page with `wget`? If that works, try to manipulate HTTP header you sent, when grabbing the page.

Answer (score 4):

You must send a `User-Agent` **HTTP Header** in the HTTP request.

Using cURL, you can set the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` option. This works:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pt-BR; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110628 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.18' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://albertacanada.com/immigration/immigrating/ainp-application-forms.aspx' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php  and this user contributed note too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#10692

Answer (score 0):

I am able to retrieve the contents of the page with the command line `curl`. So it is very likely that you need to set a user agent in your script.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
```